# Python code for sum with condition

Tags: python, list, sum, conditional-statements, slice

The task is following: sum the list elements with even indexes and multiply the result by the last list's elemet.
I have this oneliner solution code in Python.

```
array = [-37,-36,-19,-99,29,20,3,-7,-64,84,36,62,26,-76,55,-24,84,49,-65,41] 
print sum(i for i in array if array.index(i) % 2 == 0)*array[-1] if array != [] else 0
```

My result is -1476 ( The calculation is: 41*(-37-19+29+3-64+36+26+55+84-65) )

The right result is 1968.

I can't figure it out why this code is not working correctly in this particular case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a repeated element `84` in the list, thus `array.index` does not work as you expected it to be. Also, your code has a quadratic complexity which is not required.

To fix your code with a minimum amount of edit, it would look something like this:

```
array = [-37,-36,-19,-99,29,20,3,-7,-64,84,36,62,26,-76,55,-24,84,49,-65,41] 
print sum(array[i] for i in range(len(array)) if i % 2 == 0)*array[-1] if array != [] else 0
```

Comment: yeah that's the reason

Comment: from doc `array.index(i) Return the smallest i such that i is the index of the first occurrence of x in the array`.

`

Comment: I understood. This was the repeating element _84_ that causes the error. Thank You!

Answer (score 9):

This is what you are looking for:

```
array[-1] * sum(array[::2])
```

`array[::2]` traverses the array from first index to last index in steps of two, i.e., every alternate number. `sum(array[::2])` gets the sum of alternate numbers from the original list.

Using `index` will work as expected only when you are sure the list does not have duplicates, which is why your code fails to give the correct result.

Comment: This is an elegant way of solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> sum(x for i, x in enumerate(array) if not i % 2)*array[-1] 
1968
```

Use the built-in `enumerate` function, since there're duplicate elements in your list, and `list.index(x)` returns the index of the *first* element equal to `x` (as said in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)). Also take a look at the documentation on [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate).

Comment: Damn, you were faster. You could instead do `if not i % 2`, it is more Pythonic.

Comment: I would argue array[::2] is more pythonic :)

Comment: @traceur I think this is an interesting solution that uses `for` with condition.