# Reasoning behind Quadratic Complexity in this particular code

Tags: python, complexity-theory

I am asking in reference to this code:

```
array = [-37,-36,-19,-99,29,20,3,-7,-64,84,36,62,26,-76,55,-24,84,49,-65,41]
print sum(i for i in array if array.index(i) % 2 == 0)*array[-1] if array != [] else 0
```

You could see it here: [Python code for sum with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895791/python-code-for-sum-with-condition)
Is this Quadratic because of a **for** loop followed by an **if** statement, inside the brackets?

Is this code, proposed by one more person on the same page - `array[-1] * sum(array[::2])` free of Quadratic behaviour?
 I think, it's again a Quadratic one, as it has to do a traversal and that too an alternate one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keep in mind the first solution may not even be the correct one. If `array = [1, 1, 1, 1]` the result would be `4`, while I suspect you'd like to see `2`. The `.index(...)` will tell you only the first index something appears at, even if you're looking up based on another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the `array.index` that makes it quadratic.

Let's first cut all irrelevant stuff away. The conditionals are for the complexity reasoning irrelevant (we will have `array != []` and that check takes `O(1)` time). The same goes with the multiplication with `array[-1]`. So you're left with:

```
sum(i for i in array if array.index(i) % 2 == 0)
```

Now the inner is a generator and it would expand to an annonymous function looping through `array` and yielding a bunch of values, at most one per iteration. The `sum` function receives these values and adds them up.

The confusing thing maybe how a generator actually works. It actually works by running the generator intermixed with code from the consumer. This results in the complexity is the sum of the complexity of the generator and the consumer (ie `sum`). Now `sum` has linear complexity (it should have, it would if I wrote it).

So for the generator, it loops through the array, but for each element in the array it calls `array.index` which is of `O(N)` complexity.

To fix this you might use `enumerate` to avoid having to call `array.index(i)`, it may or may not be what you want to do since `array.index(i)` returns the first index for which the element is `i` which might not be the index where you actually found `i`:

```
sum(i for idx, i in enumerate(array) if idx % 2 == 0)
```

To see the difference consider the list `array = [0, 1, 2, 2]`, the first solution should sum up this to `4` since `array.index(2) == 2` so it would also add the second `2`. The later solution however will add up to `2` since `enumerate` will enumerate the elements in `array`, yielding pairs `(0,0)`, `(1,1)`, `(2,2)`, `(3,2)` - where the first component is the actual index while the second is the actual element. Here the second `2` is omitted because it's actually got from index `3`.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution is indeed quadratic: when you call `array.index` you basically iterates each time on `array` again, so it behaves like an embedded loop.

The second solution traverses the list only one time, skipping each odd indexes.

Comment: Ok, got it, first was quadratic because of a 'for' loop and an 'index' (loop)...while in the second solution, an alternate traversal would occur just one time.Thanks.